# In hindsight VS Come to think of it

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrases

How should I differentiate "in hindsight" from "come to think of it"? For me, both mean identical as it sounds like "now that I'm looking back"?

For instance, how the following sentences semantically differ from each other:

> - It was a good opportunity and I lost it! **In hindsight**, I should have taken the job!
> - It was a good opportunity and I lost it! **Come to think of it**, I should have taken the job.

Answer (score 2):

**They have the same meaning, and are interchangeable in your example.**

"Come to think of it" is slightly **less formal** English, but in speaking, this is no problem.

They would not be interchangeable if you were the narrator in a story talking about other people, or about general facts.

> - The war was lengthy.  **In hindsight**, it became clear that those who started the war did not achieve their goals.
> - The war was lengthy.  *Come to think of it*, it became clear that those who started the war did not achieve their goals.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer; just for more clarification, just don't they differ from formality point of view?

Comment: @A-friend Here's another example. ***Come to think of it,*** *maybe I'll go out after work tonight*. Here, only *come to think of it* can be used. You can't say *in hindsight* because it's talking about a future event. In your case, the event happened in the past, so both expressions are fine. *Come to think of it* does not mean *now that I'm looking back*. It means *now that I've thought about it*.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jason Bassford, but just for more clarification, according to your statements, "come to think of it" means "now that I'm thinking about it"! Therefore "in hindsight" should have an identical meaning too! Right? (I need to discover their interpreted meaning in simple language).